# adding a fragments multiple times in linear layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I want to add a fragment multiple time in the linear layout. For this purpose I'm using a For loop and passing data to the fragment. Each index has different data. My current problem is this I can only see the last fragment on the screen multipe times probably it is hiding the top fragment or any other reason. Don't understand what's the issue.

```
      categoryArrayList = dbHelper.getChannelInfo();
      fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
      ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
      for (int i = 0; i<categoryArrayList.size(); i++) {

        SubFragment frag = new SubFragment();
          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("ID", (categoryArrayList.get(i).getChannelCategoryId()));
        bundle.putString("categoryName", categoryArrayList.get(i).getChannelName());
            frag.setArguments(bundle);
            ft.add(R.id.container, frag,"fragment"+i);
    }
    ft.commit();
}
}
```

xml:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/container"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
  android:background="#252424"
  android:layout_below="@id/headercontainer"
  android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same `Bundle` for each `Fragment`'s arguments, and `FragmentTransaction`s happen asynchronously, so when they finally execute, the `Fragment`s are all reading the same arguments.

You presumably have something like the following before the loop:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
```

Move that to inside the `for` loop, before the `put*()` calls.

Comment: Now everything is gone, I cannot see any fragment on the screen.

Comment: Huh? That doesn't make any sense, if all you did was move that line to before the `put*()` calls. What exactly did you change?

Comment: I just threw your posted code into an empty project, and made a simple `SubFragment` that's just a `TextView` that displays the `categoryName` and `ID` arguments. The only thing that moving that `Bundle` line did was to correct those displayed arguments. If you're absolutely certain that that was all you changed, then there must be something else going on in your code that isn't in your post. Please edit your question with the code as you have it now, and a little more of that surrounding code.

Comment: Well, you actually changed several things from your initial post. Anyhoo, the first thing I notice is that you have several fields set as `static` that shouldn't be. In fact, everything you have that's `static` now shouldn't really be `static`. Remove the `static` from those to begin with. Then make sure that your `DatabaseHandler` is still returning what you think it is, since I can't tell if you've changed anything there.